# If $X,Y$ are two non-negative integer RVs, show that $E[XY] = \sum[P(X>=n),(Y>=m)]$

Tags: probability

I apologize for the missing latex commands but i'll try my best.

Show that $E[XY] = \sum\sum P(X \ge n, Y \ge m)$

The outer summation is for $n$ and the inner summation is for $m$ and the limits are as follows:
\begin{gather*}
1\le n < \infty\\
1\le m < \infty.
\end{gather*}

The problem before this asked me to prove that the expectation for non-negative integer RVs can be written as a distribution form instead of the conventional $xP(X=x)$ over all $x$ form.

That is, $E[X]= \sum P(X \ge n)$ for $1\le n < \infty$

I did that successfully. However, I am slightly stuck here in proving joint expectation. In order for me to use my previous results, I have to somehow break up the joint PMF as a product of marginal PMFs which is only possible if the two RVs are independent. The problem does not state that the two RVs are independent. Any thoughts on how I could approach this?

So I was thinking this \hellip. I don't know how much of it makes sense with my broken $\LaTeX$ but i'll try it anyway :).

Over all n ($\sum$ *P(X>=n, Y>=m)) * over all m ($\sum$ *P(X>=n, Y>=m

the first summation would be the expected value of Y and the expected value of X using the marginals... does it make sense?

Thank you.

-SK

PS: yes, this is a homework assignment and I am not looking for the answer. Just a nudge in the right direction would be peachy! :)

Comment: No, what you've written does not make sense -- $m$ is only defined as the index of summation for the second sum, so what does $m$ mean in the first sum?

Comment: True. In the sense of the first summation, m is held constant, while in the second summation, n is held constant. I don't know if there is any value in it, but I am trying to steer this towards taking a product of conditional expectations. The first summation, X is conditioned by Y = some value m and in the second summation, Y is conditioned by X = some value n.

Comment: But that's my whole point -- what value is it held constant at?  As written, this will be a function of $m$ and $n$... which, obviously, it should not be.

Comment: One sec, I'll try writing up a hint for you.

Comment: Okay.. I was thinking of other directions I could go with this... i'll wait :)

Comment: Whoops, I was beaten to the punch while I was typing it up!

Answer (score 0):

Either you can prove directly, in a similar way as the previous one, or you can
use that result for *conditional* probabilities: introduce another random variable $Z_n$ for each fixed $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $P(Z_n=m)\ =\ \displaystyle\frac{P(X=n,\,Y=m)}{P(X=n)}$ (of course only if $P(X=n)\ne 0$). Then we have

$$E[XY]=\sum_{n,m}nm\,P(X=n,Y=m)=\sum_nn\,\left(\sum_mm\,P(X=n,Y=m)\right)= \\
= \sum_nn\,P(X=n)\,E(Z_n)=\sum_n \left(n\,P(X=n)\,\sum_m P(Z_n\ge m)\right)\,.$$

Then ovserve that $P(Z_n\ge m)=\displaystyle\sum_{k\ge m}P(Z_n=k)=\frac{P(X=n,\,Y\ge m)}{P(X=n)}$ as the events $(X=n,Y=k)$ are pairwise disjoint, so continuing
$$E[XY]= \sum_{n,m} n\,P(X=n,\,Y\ge m)$$
and then introduce one more family of random variables, $W_m$ such that $P(W_m=n)=\displaystyle\frac{P(X=n,Y\ge m)}{P(Y\ge m)}$.

Comment: So, just so I understand your methodology let me try to re-iterate in words.. Zn and Wm are conditional probabilities for X and Y respectively, and we are saying that the conditional expectations of X and Y can be written as the form requested?

Answer (score 0):

I am finding this slightly easier to write this in a continuous setting, but indeed the proof is the same with summations. You can write that

$$
\mathbb{E}[XY] = \int_{x>0}\int_{y>0} xy \, p(x,y) \, dx \, dy
$$

and use the fact that $x = \int_{u>0} 1(u<x) \, du$ and $y = \int_{v>0} 1(v<y) \, dv$. After doing this and writing

$$
\mathbb{E}[XY] = \int_{x>0}\int_{x>0}\int_{u>0}\int_{v>0} \ldots
=
\int_{u>0}\int_{v>0} \int_{x>0}\int_{x>0} \ldots
$$

you will obtain exactly what you are looking for, namely

$$
\mathbb{E}[XY]
=
\int_{u>0}\int_{v>0} \int_{x>0}\int_{x>0} \mathbb{P}(X>u, Y > v) \, du \, dv.
$$

Indeed, this generalizes to any number of random variables.